# How do i check my password and confirm it with a password in another textbox?

Tags: android, android-studio

Im making a registration form and we have to enter password and also confirm it, when i execute the code and play in my emulator it gives a toast "Passwords dont match" even though they do match
Here is my coding:

````
next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public  void  onClick(View v) {

                String s1= eml.getText().toString();
                String p= ps.getText().toString();
                String cp= cps.getText().toString();
                String s4= fn.getText().toString();
                String s5= bno.getText().toString();
                String s6= bname.getText().toString();
                String s7= fadd.getText().toString();

                if(s1.equals("") || p.equals("") || cp.equals("")||  s4.equals("") || s5.equals("") || s6.equals("")||  s7.equals("")){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Fields are empty",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
                else {
                    if(p.equals(cp)){
                        Boolean chkmailB= db.chkmailB(s1);
                        if(chkmailB==true){
                            Boolean insert= db.insert5(s4,s1,p,s5,s6,s7);

                            if(insert==true){
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Registartion Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Intent i= new Intent(bldgmgtm.this, Login.class);
                                startActivity(i);
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Email already exists",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Passwords dont match",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });```
````

Comment: `Toast.makeText` is out side of else block

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya It did not help when i click on button its not doing anything now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add else block after if statement and put Toast in it

Comment: I tried this but my button is not responding now and giving out no toast